# javascript to display elements attributes

Tags: javascript

Below is my attempt to display an attribute or property of an element.
How can i fix this?

```js
  function showIt() {
    var el = getElementsById("demo");
    alert(el.style.color);
  }
```

```css
h1 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="demo">Hello World</h1>
<button onclick="showIt()">showIt</button>
```

Comment: First of all open console and check the error.

Comment: As IDs must be unique, there wouldn't be any pluralization on `getElementsById`. Should be `document.getElementById`

Comment: Learn to use the [Web Developer console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console). It should read: `"Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementsById is not defined"`

Answer (score 1):

First off, the function for getting elements by ID is `document.getElementById("demo");`

That should point you in a better direction....

Comment: I was going to post some updated code but it won't fit here. It illustrates that in the given code you can not get the color of the Header or Paragraph Elements until after you change it. How can I publish revised code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
var el = getElementsById("demo");
```

to

```
var el = document.getElementById("demo");
```

Comment: -- Dipendu, I made the modification you suggested but still not working.  Chrome console tells me:
<exception>: TypeError: undefined is not a function
el: undefined
-- j09681, I've never used the Ghrome console this what you were suggesting?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Most probably el is coming null in your case because when the JS is called the node 'demo' is not yet rendered. See here it works http://jsfiddle.net/akukcw9o/